# Submit HTML form using C#

Tags: c#, html, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to submit an HTML form through C# using the code below in the following WebPage:

http://liga.record.xl.pt/User/Login.aspx

I can't enter the page. Is that because it uses javascript to login?

```
private String readHtmlPage(string url)
    {
        String email = "email";
        String password = "password";

        String result = "";
        String strPost = "email=" + email + "&password=" + password; 
        StreamWriter myWriter = null;

        HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        objRequest.Method = "POST";
        objRequest.ContentLength = strPost.Length;
        objRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        try
        {
            myWriter = new StreamWriter(objRequest.GetRequestStream());
            myWriter.Write(strPost);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            myWriter.Close();
        }

        HttpWebResponse objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr =
           new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = sr.ReadToEnd();

            // Close and clean up the StreamReader
            sr.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What response do you receive? It's likely that the page requires a cookie in order to login

Comment: "Is that because it uses javascript to login?"  who you are asking.

Comment: Use Fiddler and compare the requests and their responses.

Comment: When I execute the code I get the same page, ie, I can't enter in my account because it looks like I don't do anything. If the page requires a cookie to login, what should I do?